# Recuperar plugins instalados por API REST

Tags: wordpress, api

Lo que deseo es hacer un sistema donde pueda monitorear todas las paginas que administro. Estas paginas las monto con Wordpress, y se que este tiene una API para gestionar contenido como post y demás, pero lo que deseo es listar todos los plugins que esta instalado en esa pagina.

¿Alguna orientación de como puedo realizarlo?

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación de Wordpress?

Comment: Si claro, pero solo encuentro con post, paginas y otros apartados, pero no mencionan nada de recuperar plugin con la api rest

Comment: le pregunté a un amigo mio sobre el tema, esto fue lo que me dijo: "$cualquier_variable = get_plugins(); || eso le devuelve un array con plugins, que lo pase por var_dump si quiere saber como trabajarlo."

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por tu consejo. No trabaja directamente con la API pero es una opcion

Comment: de nada hermano, espero encuentres pronta solución :D